# AutoHotKey how to know the retrieved path is for a file or folder?

Tags: file, loops, autohotkey

I'm using the loop, filepattern to retrieve a set of files and folder
what I want is to know how to make AHK send me a message if it's folder and if it's a folder just skip it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## FileGetAttrib

> Reports whether a file or folder is read-only, hidden, etc.

However, you can use it to determine if something is a folder or a file.

#### Example

```
MyPath := "C:\Windows"
FileGetAttrib, MyAttributes, %MyPath%
If InStr(MyAttributes,"D")
    MsgBox I am a folder.
Else
    MsgBox I am a file.
```

Source: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FileGetAttrib.htm

Comment: Not that I'm concerned very much, but what's the point in copying some elses answer and adding a fancy quote? Is this how answers are expected to be done? Just wondering. Hope you can help me out, you're the one who's been to this page for a longer time obviously.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not notice your answer. I did not mean to wrong you... :( But also, I noticed that `FileGetAttrib` was not mentioned at all in case future users are looking for a non-loop version? And as a guideline, adding a link to the documentation is always a good start. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope these three ways will help you understand:

```
recurse = 1
loop, *.*, 2, %recurse%
    msgbox, %a_index%: FOLDER %a_loopFileName%
loop, *.*, 0, %recurse%
    msgbox, %a_index%: FILE %a_loopFileName%
loop, *.*, 1, %recurse%
{
    ifinstring, a_loopFileAttrib, D
        msgbox, %a_index%: FOLDER %a_loopFileName%
    else
        msgbox, %a_index%: FILE %a_loopFileName%
}
```